# GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe returns empty list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am testing MSFT Graph's SharedWithMe REST API, and I continually get an empty collection returned from the service.

I have verified that there is a document (DriveItem) shared with me by a friend from another organization.  I did this using the default, OneDrive webclient.  There is a single document listed in that "tab" as expected.

I logged into my account (OneDrive Business) via Graph Explorer, and made sure I had Files.ReadWrite.All permission.  I then issued the sample REST API to retrieve the items shared with me...but this is the response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
"value": []
}
```

Other REST calls via Graph Explorer do return results I would expect for my account, so I am positive I am authenticated properly.

I expect this API to have returned a collection with one (remote) DriveItem in it, but alas, it does not.

Since the REST service is returning a 200 (it's not syntactical), I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar experience. If a file is shared to me by someone in my org then it shows up in graph api but if it is shared by someone outside my org it doesn't show up in graph api. In the OneDrive user interface, both files show up in the Shared section.

Answer (score 2):

It is not documented, but add the `allowExternal` querystring parameter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe?allowExternal=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works when you have authorized token using Delegated Permissions.

Comment: I think the poster is properly authenticated, as he would recieve an incorrect response from Graph API if he did not have permissions setup properly. Note, he also used the Graph Explorer which enables you to bypass this step entirely. Also note that there are two different ways to authenticate: delegated and app-based. If he is using app-based authentication, then he would not need delegated permissions anyway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http